# Query to give count of unique results in column A but then split by values in column B

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm trying to create a SQL query to count the number of occurences of a dynamic value in one column, but then have this count split by what is in another column.

If the table I'm getting the data from looks something like:

```
id  | Team | Period |
____________________
1   | A    |   1    |
2   | B    |   1    |
3   | B    |   1    |
4   | A    |   1    |
5   | E    |   2    |
6   | D    |   3    |
7   | A    |   3    |
8   | A    |   3    |
9   | B    |   4    |
10  | A    |   4    |
11  | C    |   4    |

etc...
```

I want to get a list of how many times each team appears per period like so.

```
team  | period | count  |
_________________________
  A   |   1    |   2    |
  B   |   1    |   2    |
  C   |   1    |   0    |
  D   |   1    |   0    |
  E   |   1    |   0    |
  A   |   2    |   0    |
  B   |   2    |   0    |
  C   |   2    |   0    |
  D   |   2    |   0    |
  E   |   2    |   0    |
  A   |   3    |   2    |
```

This will be used in a PHP page to then make an assoc array and print out the data for reporting purposes.

I have previously used things like

```sql
SELECT sum(case when somecolumn = 'blah' then 1 else 0 end) as blah_count
```

But I can't do that here, because in future the names of the teams may change to a currently unknown value, so I can't use the names in the query. (and no, I won't be told about this so I can change the query.) So I need a query where it both gives count of any occurrence in the team column and splits them by period. Period will always be a number from 1 to 13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `cross join` all distinct values of `team`s and `period`s, and then `left join` the original table and aggregate.

```
select
    te.team,
    pe.period,
    count(ta.team) cnt
from 
    (select distinct team from mytable) te
    cross join (select distinct period from mytable) pe
    left join mytable ta 
        on ta.team = te.team
        and ta.period = pe.period
group by te.team, pe.period
order by pe.period, te.team
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=6f408ee4c9325f2c2be2b98f01379147)**:

```
team | period | cnt
:--- | -----: | --:
A    |      1 |   2
B    |      1 |   2
C    |      1 |   0
D    |      1 |   0
E    |      1 |   0
A    |      2 |   0
B    |      2 |   0
C    |      2 |   0
D    |      2 |   0
E    |      2 |   1
A    |      3 |   2
B    |      3 |   0
C    |      3 |   0
D    |      3 |   1
E    |      3 |   0
A    |      4 |   1
B    |      4 |   1
C    |      4 |   1
D    |      4 |   0
E    |      4 |   0
```

Comment: Perfect, that works just like I wanted. Now I've just got to figure out what each of those join steps all mean so I can reproduce it with different data in future.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT team,period,count(*) as count
from TABLENAME group by team
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to do the tally part correctly, but does not account for splitting up the data like I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Why not pivot the periods?

```
select team,
       sum( period = 1 ) as period_1,
       sum( period = 2 ) as period_2,
       sum( period = 3 ) as period_3,
       sum( period = 4 ) as period_4
from t
group by team;
```

You seem to know that there are four periods.

Comment: This does also work for my needs, and is certainly simpler to understand from a readability point of view for me.  Yours was also a bit faster (at least, using my example data from my real table.) You method =  Showing rows 0 - 1 (2 total, Query took 0.1776 seconds.) GMB's method = Showing rows 0 - 13 (14 total, Query took 0.2166 seconds. However I'm sure those numbers would change with much more data rather than the small faux stuff I'm developing with.

This isn't really GMB's fault, as he just posted it exactly how I asked the result to look, rather than taking a wider view like you did.